# GDAL Vector to Raster Conversion Not Working

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I have a point shapefile that has a field AEP_fuzz and I want to convert to a raster.  The field type is double and I get the following error:
[image]

> GDAL command: gdal_rasterize -l INPUT -a AEP_fuzz -tr 25.0 25.0
> -a_nodata 0.0 -te 260332.3116 6033180.9488 271585.3921 6044263.9006 -ot Float32 -of RST C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_lZvSiH/3ea68677900f401b92d690a50d953713/INPUT.gpkg
> C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_lZvSiH/367a084fbc1840deb5a6c730e616ed52/OUTPUT.rst
> GDAL command output: ERROR 1: Failed to find field AEP_fuzz on layer
> INPUT, skipping. ERROR 1:
> C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_lZvSiH/367a084fbc1840deb5a6c730e616ed52/OUTPUT.rst,
> band 1: Failed to compute statistics, no valid pixels found in
> sampling. Process returned error code 1 Execution completed in 0.26
> seconds Results: {'OUTPUT':
> 'C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_lZvSiH/367a084fbc1840deb5a6c730e616ed52/OUTPUT.rst'}
>
> Loading resulting layers Algorithm 'Rasterize (vector to raster)'
> finished

Comment: The name of the input layer is "AEP Hapitat Map Fuzzy Map", isn't it? Does it appear between double quotes in the generated request? Or is "INPUT" really the layer name that is used in the command?

Comment: You are correct.  It was a temporary file I was trying to rasterize.  I saved the file to disk before rasterization and it now works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot perform rasterization on a temporary output. Save to disk then perform rasterization.